# EF core eager loading not working but explict works

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

when i replace all navigation pro to virtual and lazy loading set to false not working
but when i use include on query object i works i have 2 level relation and EF core 5.0.10
model is

```
    public partial class SalGsub
    {
        public long SaleId { get; set; }
        public long? Sstore { get; set; }
        public long? Sproduct { get; set; }
        public string Sunit { get; set; }
        public decimal? Squntity { get; set; }
        public decimal? Sqdisc { get; set; }
        public decimal? SunitPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal? StotalPrice { get; set; }
        public long? SalGlnk { get; set; }

        public virtual SalesGood SalGlnkNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Product SproductNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Store SstoreNavigation { get; set; }
    }
   public partial class SalesGood
    {
        public SalesGood()
        {
            SalGsubs = new HashSet<SalGsub>();
        }

        public long SalegoodId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SaleDate { get; set; }
        public decimal? TotalAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal? Discount { get; set; }
        public decimal? Total { get; set; }
        public long? BankAccount { get; set; }
        public string BankName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CheckDate { get; set; }
        public string Checkno { get; set; }
        public decimal? Paied { get; set; }

        public virtual BankAcc BankAccountNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SalGsub> SalGsubs { get; set; }
    }
```

fluentapi code is

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<SalGsub>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.SaleId);

                entity.ToTable("SalGSub");

                entity.Property(e => e.Sproduct).HasColumnName("SProduct");

                entity.Property(e => e.Sqdisc)
                    .HasColumnType("decimal(10, 2)")
                    .HasColumnName("SQDisc");

                entity.Property(e => e.Squntity)
                    .HasColumnType("decimal(10, 2)")
                    .HasColumnName("SQuntity");

                entity.Property(e => e.Sstore).HasColumnName("SStore");

                entity.Property(e => e.StotalPrice)
                    .HasColumnType("decimal(10, 2)")
                    .HasColumnName("STotalPrice");

                entity.Property(e => e.Sunit)
                    .HasMaxLength(10)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("SUnit")
                    .UseCollation("SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS");

                entity.Property(e => e.SunitPrice)
                    .HasColumnType("decimal(10, 2)")
                    .HasColumnName("SUnitPrice");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.SalGlnkNavigation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.SalGsubs)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.SalGlnk)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_SalGSub_SalesGood");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.SproductNavigation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.SalGsubs)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.Sproduct)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_SalGSub_Product");
                
                entity.HasOne(d => d.SstoreNavigation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.SalGsubs)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.Sstore)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_SalGSub_Store");
            });
modelBuilder.Entity<SalesGood>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.SalegoodId);

                entity.ToTable("SalesGood");

                entity.Property(e => e.BankName)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .UseCollation("Albanian_100_BIN");

                entity.Property(e => e.CheckDate).HasColumnType("date");

                entity.Property(e => e.Checkno)
                    .HasMaxLength(25)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .UseCollation("Albanian_100_BIN");

                entity.Property(e => e.CustomerName)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .UseCollation("SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS");

                entity.Property(e => e.Discount).HasColumnType("decimal(10, 2)");

                entity.Property(e => e.Paied).HasColumnType("decimal(10, 2)");

                entity.Property(e => e.SaleDate).HasColumnType("date");

                entity.Property(e => e.Total).HasColumnType("decimal(10, 0)");

                entity.Property(e => e.TotalAmount).HasColumnType("decimal(10, 2)");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.BankAccountNavigation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.SalesGoods)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.BankAccount)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_SalesGood_BankAcc");
            });
```

this working with productnavigation have its value as explict include and then include

```
var temp = context.SalesGoods.Include(x=>x.SalGsubs).ThenInclude(xx=>xx.SproductNavigation).Where(x => x.SalegoodId == id).Select(x => x).SingleOrDefault();
```

this **not** working SproductNavigation is null

```
 var temp = context.SalesGoods.Where(x => x.SalegoodId == id).Select(x => x).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: _"and lazy loading set to false "_ so lazy loading is disabled and not working. Why do you expect it to work?  Have you called `.UseLazyLoadingProxies()` for context options set up?

Comment: Turning off lazy loading does *not* make EF eager load everything... It simply removes the proxy ability to trigger a lazy load, resulting in references being populated if the context was already tracking them, or left #null.